# List of Resources for EE developers and users?

Tags: general-knowledge

I got this idea from the [Russian Language and Usage](https://russian.stackexchange.com/faq) site. Since "lists of links" are discouraged by the StackOverflow rules, this is a *single question* with a list of relevant resources for folks using EE.

I am answering my own question with a couple of initial resources, and setting that answer to [Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) mode. **Please add resources to the single answer** rather than creating separate answers; that way the resources can stay nicely categorized.

Comment: Interesting idea, although you may want to set your answer as the "accepted" answer otherwise it will throw off our question-to-answer ratio

Comment: Patrick - It says I can't for 2 days since it's my own answer. But I will as soon as it lets me!

Comment: Added in training info for EE Users. What else is there?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**ExpressionEngine main website — https://expressionengine.com**

**ExpressionEngine GitHub repo — https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine**

**ExpressionEngine official forums — https://expressionengine.com/forums**

**ExpressionEngine Slack Channel — https://expressionengine.com/blog/join-us-in-slack#join-us-on-slack**

---

## Official Documentation

- EE7 — https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/
- EE6 — https://docs.expressionengine.com/v6/
- EE5 — https://docs.expressionengine.com/v5/
- EE4 — https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/
- EE3 — https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/
- EE2 — https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/
- EE1 — https://docs.expressionengine.com/v1/
- CodeIgniter 2 — https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/

The official documentation is the most thorough resource on EE usage and development and should always be considered first, especially as a novice learning EE.

---

## ExpressionEngine Add-ons

- ExpressionEngine Add-on Store — https://expressionengine.com/add-ons
  (official add-ons store)
- devot:ee — http://devot-ee.com
  (list of ExpressionEngine addons with a store, currently mostly abandoned)

---

## ExpressionEngine Conference and Meetups

- EEConf — https://www.eeconf.com
- EE Conference YouTube channel — https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCOp4MZ1ggdKSsZ3lPa6yiw

---

## Learning Recources

- ExpressionEngine University - https://u.expressionengine.com/
- ExpressionEngine TV - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtG8DcWT9s4ILWGq0m1Bpxg

---

## EE Template Examples

- [Alistapart.com open-source template](https://github.com/alistapart/AListApart)

---

## Topic Resources

#### *Parse Order*

- [EE Documentation on the template engine](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/template_engine.html)
- [Low's parse order reference](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf)

#### *Template Partials and Stash*

- [Template partials using Stash](http://eeinsider.com/articles/template-partials-using-stash/) by Adrienne Travis
- [More Stash Examples](http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/cms/more-stash-examples/) by John Faulds

#### *EE URL and Segments*

- [ExpressionEngine URL Schematic](http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine_url_schematic) by James Smith
  (How EE deciphers whether a segement is a template, an entry, or something else)

#### *Multilingual Development (i18n)*

- [Multi-language Solutions for ExpressionEngine](http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine/) by Christofer Sandin

#### *.htaccess*

- [EE Documentation on removing index.php from URLs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html)

#### *Optimisation*

- [EE Documentation on optimization](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/optimization/index.html)

#### *404 Pages*

- [EE Answers entry on 404 pages](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-a-standard-way-to-do-404-pages-with-structure) by the community here

#### *Configuring EE for Multiple Environments*

- [NSM Config Bootstrap](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-config-bootstrap)
- [Focus Labs' Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config)
- [Developing ExpressionEngine sites with MAMP, Git (Tower) and Beanstalk](http://www.johnfaulds.com.au/journal/developing-expressionengine-sites-with-mamp-git-tower-and-beanstalk-part-1/)

---

## Resources for Add-On Developers

#### *Tutorials*

- [Building an ExpressionEngine Add-on](http://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/how-to-develop-expressionengine-add-on/) screencast from Mijingo by Low

#### *Presentations*

- [Add-On Development: EE Expects that Every Developer will do his Duty](http://www.slideshare.net/reedmaniac/addon-development-ee-expects-that-every-developer-will-do-his-duty-2494809) (and [presentation.txt](http://www.solspace.com/downloads/eeci2009/presentation.txt) with non-slide text, too) by Paul Burdick, Lead Developer at Solspace (October 2009).
- <s>[So, you wanna build an add-on](http://www.slideshare.net/lodewijkschutte/so-you-wanna-build-an-addon) by Low (October 2012)</s>

#### *Tools*

- <s>[pkg.io — Package Builder for ExpressionEngine](http://pkg.io/)
  (**Note**: rename `lang.module_name.php` to `module_name_lang.php`; be weary of single quotes in module descriptions as that will break in your language file)</s>
- [generator-ee-addon — An ExpressionEngine Add-On generator for Yeoman](https://github.com/rsanchez/generator-ee-addon) by Rob Sanchez based off work by Abban Dunne
- other resources go here